# how to stop Makefile from printing rule lines onto shell

Tags: makefile

I am using a makefile to build a set of C files. The rule of compiling the .c files to .o is as follows:

```
%.o : %.c
    printf "\ncompiling $<\n"
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

When this is executed, I"m observing following output on the shell:

```
printf "\ncompiling source/abcxyz.c\n"
compiling source/abcxyz.c
gcc.exe <other compiler inputs>
```

I want to prevent `printf "\ncompiling source/abcxyz.c\n"` from being printed to the the terminal.

How to do achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefix the rule command with a `@` sign:

```
@printf "\ncompiling $<\n"
```